# Trying to select the `button` element to add the onClick event

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

How can I select the `button` element to add the onClick event?
I am trying to change the 'add' to 'done' on every click.

```
function shoppingData(datas) {
   datas.forEach((data) => {
        wrap.innerHTML += `<tr>
                             <td><button>${add}</button></td>
                          </tr>`
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```js
var boton = document.querySelector("#boton");
boton.addEventListener('click', () => alert('Button clicked'));
```

```html
<button id="boton"> Click me </button>
```

Comment: Received an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at shoppingData`. Thanks for trying! @sonEtLumiere

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you need to do is the following:

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
   [your function]
})
```

This will grab all buttons on the page and let you make whatever changes you want to them.

Comment: I received an reference error, `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at shoppingData` . I'm trying to write the code before `wrap.innerHTML`

Comment: Ah, my bad, I assumed you had jQuery installed. You might want to consider adding jQuery to your project as it makes DOM manipulation way, way easier than just using plain javascript.